# How to add an existing key to the certutil key database

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate, nss

I have created an SSL keypair with OpenSSL. I uploaded the Certificate Signing Request to my SSL Certificate provider and got my certificate files.

I added my certificate and the required CA certificates to the certificate database using certutil. However, when I try to serve HTTPS pages, I get this error message: "Cannot find private key for certificate".

I have the private key in a .key file, however it seems that certutil does not have an option to add keys to the key store, although it has the option to generate new keypairs and put them in the database.

Is there a way to get my private key into the key database from certutil?

Comment: Obivously you have a web server problem but you do not tell, what webserver you are using.

Comment: He has a certificate database problem, not really a web server problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, certutil doesn't have an option to add private keys.  You need to use pk12util for that.

If your private key is in PKCS12 format, you can add it to the key/cert database with

```
pk12util -i keyfile.key -d/path/to/database -W password
```

If it's in PEM format, you'll need to convert it to PKCS12 first by

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out server.pfx -inkey server.key -in server.crt -certfile CAcert.crt
```

then import server.pfx with pk12util as above.

Unfortunately certutil and pk12util often don't come with man pages, but `certutil -H` and `pk12util -H` provide some help.  There are also some [online docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/NSS/Tools) and [man pages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS/Reference/NSS_tools).

Comment: You command did not work, however, Eric's suggestion here did: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27176982/749521

Comment: @StevenRoose: OK.  Please consider editing my answer to make it work.